# Calculator Form in Javascript Returning Wrong Numbers

Tags: javascript, forms, calculator

Trying to build a calculator in Javascript to let people figure out how much their commute costs them and how much they can save by using my company's shuttle service. For some reason, the numbers are all wrong and I can't figure out why.

```
<script>
function calc(){
    var miles=document.getElementById('miles').value;
    var tolls=document.getElementById('tolls').value;
    var days=document.getElementById('days').value;
    var parking=document.getElementById('parking').value;
    var cost= (tolls * days * 4) + (miles * days * 4 * 0.54) + parking;
    document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML=cost;
    var savings= cost - 200;
    document.getElementById('savings').innerHTML=savings;
    return false
}
</script>
<form>
<p>Miles Per Day You Commute <input type="text" id="miles"/></p>
<p>Days Per Week You Commute <input type="text" id="days" /></p>
<p>Tolls per Day <input type="text" id="tolls" /></p>
<p>Cost of Parking at Work <input type="text" onChange="calc()" id="parking" /></p>
<input type="button" onClick="calc()" value="Calculate" />
</form>
<p>Your Current Cost of Commuting: <div id="cost"></div> per month</p>
<p>Your Savings With Joule: <div id="savings"></div> per month</p>
```

For reference, the 0.54 refers the the $0.54 per mile IRS suggested reimbursement rate. The 200 refers to the amount of money my shuttle costs.

[image: Here are my outputs]

The actual outputs should be:

```
Cost: $516
Savings: $316
```

Comment: It would help if you could post your inputs and the output you received that was incorrect...

Comment: @War10ck Just added it

Comment: Your inputs are type text. So before doing math with their values you need to convert them to numbers: parseFloat(input.value)

Comment: @yBrodsky I must be missing something because when making all of the inputs numbers, it returns NaN.

Comment: create a jsfiddle with a working demo of this. Otherwise is impossible to help you

Comment: @yBrodsky never used it before but here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/qhywc4zz/

Comment: This works: https://jsfiddle.net/ka415gyw/ Lacks validation and a whole bunch of shit, but it works.

Comment: @yBrodsky Just tried it. Got the same answers as my screenshot. Answers that should be there are below the screenshot.

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/ka415gyw/1/

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please accept it (click the checkmark) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `parking` is a string because it's coming directly from a text field, so when you're attempting to do your `cost` calculation

```
//  cost= ( 5    *   5  * 4) + ( 20   *  5   * 4 * 0.54) +  "200"
//  cost= (      100       ) + (          216          ) +  "200"
//  cost= (316) + "200"
//  cost= "316200"  
var cost= (tolls * days * 4) + (miles * days * 4 * 0.54) + parking;
```

You're APPENDING the STRING value of `parking` to the INTEGER value of the previous math statements.  That's why your numbers look like "316200", because you're literally attaching "316" and "200" instead of adding the two like you're intending.

You need to parse `parking` as an int first and then your math will work properly.  Alternatively, you can times `parking` by 1 to convert it to a number:

```
var cost= (tolls * days * 4) + (miles * days * 4 * 0.54) + (parking * 1);
```